# Stop PHP script execution through externally updated variable in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables, laravel-9

#### I'm trying to stop the execution of an php script in runtime triggered by the user.

My planned approach is to make an ajax call to the server, setting a session variable which is then looked up by the first already running script every now and then to determine if the process should stop or continue running. Hope that makes sense:)
I already found some examples of people doing the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073307/11819569) or with files instead of sessions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278918/11819569).

Now my problem is that I would like to use the session for my approach instead of the solution doing it with temporary files and the mentioned approach with sessions doesn't seem to work for me in Laravel 9.

#### The result I'm looking for:

1. start first php script (runs maybe 30 seconds)
2. make ajax call to server & set session variable `stop_execution = true`
3. the first php script which is still running detects the change in `stop_execution === true` & stops execution.

#### The behaviour I get:

1. start first php script (runs maybe 30 seconds)
2. make ajax call to server & set session variable `stop_execution = true`
3. the first php script which is still running **doesn't detect** the change in `stop_execution === true` & **runs until it finishes by itself**.
4. the next time I run the first php script again it immediately detects the change in `stop_execution === true` & stops execution.

My thought on why this is happening is that the session variables doesn't get refreshed inside the first script after checking them for the first time. Maybe there is a way to force pull all new changes from the session variables while the first script is running? Did somebody have the same issues with Laravel? It seems like this is working with session variables when not using Laravel. I think it has something to do with Laravel and how the sessions are handled.

I would appreciate any advice 
Thanks a lot!

---

### Code:

First script executed at the beginning

```
private function longRunningFunction()
{
    // check session variable every iteration and exit while loop if === true
    while ($condition === true && ! session('cancel_computation')) {
        // do stuff ...
    }
    // reset session variable to false after finishing
    session(['cancel_computation' => false]);

    return $result;
}
```

Second script executed on ajax call

```
public function cancelComputationFunction()
{
    // set session variable to be true
    session(['cancel_computation' => true]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not advice you to use sessions for this.

They are initialized on script start and I have never seen somebody re-fetch them in the same script.
Nor am I able to find such functionality when researching online.

What you could do though, is to utitlize the Cache facade.

It is very well suited for what you want and it very lightweight no matter which driver you choose to use under the hood in Laravel.

So instead of:

```
public function cancelComputationFunction()
{
    // set session variable to be true
    session(['cancel_computation' => true]);
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
public function cancelComputationFunction()
{
    // set cache variable to be true
    Cache::put('cancel_computation_' . session()->getId(), true);
}
```

And likewise inside the long-running part of the script.

Comment: Thx for the tip but sadly I get the same result using the Cache facade. I implemented it exactly like you mentioned... Any ideas?

Comment: I have only suggested the changes needed in the `cancelComputationFunction()`. You youself need to change `longRunningFunction()` to be using cache. Did you do that? And how does that code looks now?

Comment: Yes, I did that too... I updated my question to include the changes I made in both files. The behaviour didn't change at all even if I was using the cache facade `Cache::put()` like you suggested instead of the global cache helper `cache()` in both files.

Comment: I now have found the problem I had the whole time... I was only testing on my local machine and therefore my second ajax request sent for setting the cache variable could only be processed AFTER the first one had finished. That's why i got the same behaviour both ways... Thx for your suggestion to use cache instead of sessions 